# Unit-Test AspNetCore with full .NET Framework

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-core

While testing a Asp.NetCore (2.2) with full .NET Framework (4.7.2) with Unit-Tests (MSTest 1.3.2) with the help of the Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost (2.2.0) NuGet, I receive following exception

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Buffers, Version=4.0.2.0
```

However, I did choose `Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost 2.2.0` and downloaded all dependencies automatically. Hence, the packages.json looks like following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.2.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.Abstractions" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Abstractions" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.FileSystemGlobbing" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.ObjectPool" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Options" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="MSTest.TestAdapter" version="1.3.2" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="MSTest.TestFramework" version="1.3.2" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="11.0.2" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.Buffers" version="4.5.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.Collections.Immutable" version="1.5.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.ComponentModel.Annotations" version="4.5.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.Data.SQLite" version="1.0.109.2" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.Data.SQLite.Core" version="1.0.109.2" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" version="1.0.109.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.Data.SQLite.Linq" version="1.0.109.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" version="4.5.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.IO.Pipelines" version="4.5.2" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.Memory" version="4.5.1" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.Numerics.Vectors" version="4.4.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.Reflection.Metadata" version="1.6.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" version="4.5.1" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.Text.Encodings.Web" version="4.5.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions" version="4.5.1" targetFramework="net472" />
</packages>
```

The test-class

```
[TestInitialize]
public void TestInitialize()
{
    server = new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder().UseStartup<Startup>());
    Client = server.CreateClient();
}

private HttpClient Client { get; set; }

[TestMethod]
public async Task GetDatabaseId()
{
    var response = await Client.GetAsync("api/values");
    ;
}
```

While debugging the test, the exception "... System.Buffers,..." gets thrown at the line `app.UseMvc();` in the Startup.cs (Default generated class with zero changes)

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Comment: Why are you using net framework for testing instead of .netcore?

Comment: Because the Unit-Test Library has to reference and use .NET Framework 4.7 libs.
And the Web-API has to be a .NET Core with a Full .NET backend...

Answer (score 0):

`System.Buffers` is part of .NET Core, and therefore wouldn't be covered by one of the specific NuGet packages you're using. In other words, it's assumed to be part of the framework. However, .NET Framework 4.7 doesn't include this namespace. You'll need to explicitly add the `System.Buffers` NuGet package.

Comment: Ok. But the packages.json already includes that namespace.
<package id="System.Buffers" version="4.5.0" targetFramework="net472" />